# C# Case Sensitivity in Switch-statement

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, case-sensitive

I'm working a little with `switch` statements and want to know how to ignore the case sensitivity when it comes to input values.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace SwitchStatements
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Start:
        Console.WriteLine("Please Input the Grade");
        char grade = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (grade)
        {
            case 'A':
                Console.WriteLine("Excellent Work!");
                break;
            case 'B':
                Console.WriteLine("Very Good Effort! Just a couple of     Errors =)");
                break;
            case 'C':
                Console.WriteLine("You Passed. Push Yourself Next Time");
                break;
            case 'D':
                Console.WriteLine("Better put in more effort next time. I know you can do better");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Grade.");
                break;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        goto Start;
    }
}
}
```

If I put 'a' in instead of 'A' it returns the default response.

Can I use perhaps a .Comparison of some sort? If so where would I put it?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `ConsoleKey` as condition for `switch`, the code will be like the following.

```
var grade =Console.ReadKey().Key;
switch (grade)
{
    case ConsoleKey.A:
        Console.WriteLine("Excellent Work!");
        break;
    case ConsoleKey.B:
        // Something here
        break;    
    case ConsoleKey.C:
        // Something here
        break;

    case ConsoleKey.D:
        // Something here
        break;          
    case ConsoleKey.E:
       // Something here
        break;             
    default:
       // Something here
        break;
}
```

So that you can avoid converting the input to uppercase/Lower case, and then it goes for another conversion To Char. Simply use `ConsoleKey` Enumeration inside the switch.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`ToUpper();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx) Like

```
Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
```

and to get saved from the error of getting more charaters with `Console.ReadLine()` you can use

```
char grd = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper());
```

Comment: @MohitShrivastava : Appreciate the comment for compelling user to accept a partial answer, With all respect let me add few notes here,  `Console.ReadLine()` allows the user to input more than one character, in such cases `Convert.ToChar()` will give you errors :).

Comment: @MohitShrivastava 1) Switch blocks are fully capable of taking a `string` value as a conditional, so there's no need to convert back to `char`; 2) The value of `KeyChar` is itself a `char`, so the conversion to `string` is unnecessary as you can just use `char.ToUpper`; 3) Working with `char` in general is unnecessary as you can use `ConsoleKeyInfo.Key` which is an enum value and is thus easily used as a switch conditional without having to worry about character case.

Answer (score 2):

you can use like following also

```
   char grade = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpperInvariant());
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupperinvariant.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
char grade = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
```

To

```
char grade = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.toupper(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Convert to uppercase before switch like below,

```
grade = Char.ToUpper(grade);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write Switch on grade.ToUpper() like this and don't change change it's value, may  be you will need it after

```
    char grade = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

    switch (grade.ToUpper())
    {
        case 'A':
            Console.WriteLine("Excellent Work!");
            break;
        case 'B':
            Console.WriteLine("Very Good Effort! Just a couple of     Errors =)");
            break;
        case 'C':
            Console.WriteLine("You Passed. Push Yourself Next Time");
            break;
        case 'D':
            Console.WriteLine("Better put in more effort next time. I know you can do better");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Grade.");
            break;
    }
```

Comment: @S.Petrosov :  With all respect let me add few notes here, Console.ReadLine() allows the user to input more than one character, in such cases Convert.ToChar() will give you errors :).

Comment: What would you recommend using instead?

Comment: @MarcusBristow You should use Convert.ToChar(Console.Read()) instead of Console.ReadLine() if you want to read only 1 char.

Answer (score 1):

You may fall from one case to another like this

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Boolean validInputRead = false;
    Char grade;

    while(!validInputRead) 
    {
        validInputRead = true;

        Console.WriteLine("Please Input the Grade");
        grade = Convert.ToChar(Console.Read());

        switch (grade)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                Console.WriteLine("Excellent Work!");
                break;

            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                Console.WriteLine("Very Good Effort! Just a couple of     Errors =)");
                break;

            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                Console.WriteLine("You Passed. Push Yourself Next Time");
                break;

            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                Console.WriteLine("Better put in more effort next time. I know you can do better");
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Grade.");
                validInputRead = false;
                break;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

## EDIT

- Changed from `Console.ReadLine()` to `Console.Read()` as suggested
- Added `while(!validInputRead)` as requested

Comment: This would involve a bunch of useless repetition... it's better to convert the input to uppercase and then deal with it.

Comment: What will happen if i enter `A+` when the console prompt me `"Please Input the Grade"`

Comment: it will crash because `A+` is not a char

Comment: throws a `System.FormatException`

Comment: Could you give me an example of this while(true) wrapping? So this will stop the program for exiting after the input value has been entered?

Comment: According to the official C# terminology, this is not called "falling from one case to another". In your code portion `case 'A': case 'a': Console.WriteLine("Excellent Work!"); break;` there is only one ___switch section___ which happens to posses two ___switch labels___. From the language specification: _If the end point of the statement list of a switch section is reachable, a compile-time error occurs. This is known as the "no fall through" rule. [...] Unlike C and C++, execution of a switch section is not permitted to "fall through" to the next switch section_

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen agreed. it's all about paradigms :-)

Comment: @MarcusBristow sure. Will do later

Comment: @MarcusBristow Done. Was busy :-/

Answer (score 0):

string letterGrade;
            int grade = 0;

```
        // This will hold the final letter grade
        Console.Write("Input the grade :");

        switch (grade)
        {

            case 1:
                // 90-100 is an A
                letterGrade = "A";
                Console.WriteLine("grade b/n 90-100");
                break;
            case 2:
                // 80-89 is a B
                letterGrade = "B";
                Console.WriteLine("grade b/n 80-89");
                break;
            case 3:
                // 70-79 is a C
                letterGrade = "C";
                Console.WriteLine("grade b/n 70-79");
                break;
            case 4:
                // 60-69 is a D
                letterGrade = "D";
                Console.WriteLine(" grade b/n 60-69 ");
                break;
            default:
                // point whic is less than 59
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid grade");

                break;
        }
```

Comment: How does this help? It doesn't do what the original code does.